# Android: Efficient way to read logcat output

Tags: android, bufferedreader, logcat

How can one read the output of a running process in the most efficient manner

Let me explain what i am trying to achieve.

I am trying to read logcat via my app on the phone

I want to make it such that any update in the logcat is instantly reflected and the app is efficient , like less battery consumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[android-logger](https://code.google.com/p/android-logger/) may be of interest to you.  Its an open source app that allows you to read logcat from an app on your phone.  I'm sure you will find the code you need in this app.

Comment: For those who need a link to the said FIRST app directly: https://code.google.com/p/android-logger/

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. Eclipse.  There is a "logCat" view you can add Window->Show View...->Other->Android->LogCat.
2. ADB.  Use the android debugger console.  Run "adb logcat" (this is the same as #1 but without eclipse).

To be efficient:

1. Don't log too much in the app!
2. Use filters.  In eclipse's logCat you can filter by text, tag, etc...
3. Battery doesn't matter.  The log is output over USB (which should be allowing you to charge anyway!)

Comment: I don't think the question is how to view logcat, rather it seems to be about how to display it from an app.