# Getting information from logCat window

Tags: android, logcat

How to get information from the LogCat window?

Comment: Take a look at this question --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839539/android-effecient-way-to-read-logcat-output

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

If you add something like `Log.v("tag", "value");` in your code,
You can see that in  LogCat window.

Comment: The gool is not to add something to see it in window LogCat but I have an url in this window ant i want to get this url from my code.

Comment: in window LogCat there is a message  with tag="webkit" and message contain url . I want to put this message in a String

Answer (score 0):

You can click Windows ->ShowView->Other-> Android ->Logcat

Refer to Images 1 and Images 2

[image]

and [image]

and in the code use v -> Verbose and d -> Debug and E-> Error I -> Information, W -> Warning

Comment: The gool is not  to see an information in window LogCat but I have an url in this window ant i want to get this url from my code.

Comment: hmm what is in sex_view.java ;) ?

Comment: @Reno: Nothing , Normal Code, Only