# Android - adding class to manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm a newbie to Android, so pardon me for asking (probably) the obvious.

I've created a class similar to this:

```
public class myClass  {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
```

but when I try running the app in the emulator it gives me the "The application has stopped unexpectedly".
I'm guessing that it has something to do with registering or adding this class to the manifest, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.
I'd very much appreciate your help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't have to add helper classes to the manifest (unless it's an Activity or Intent).  Can you post the stack trace? It should be available via the Dalvik Debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Your class is not an activtiy (at least the way you posted it ;-) so no entry in the manifest is needed.

Have a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html for information about activities and how to add them to the manifest. The best way to understand this when starting with Android is to create a hello world demo (can be done in eclipse when creating a new project)

Have you looked in the LogCat what the crash is about? There should be an error stack trace printed. Here [Getting information from logCat window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323454/getting-information-from-logcat-windows) someone explained by screenshots how to use that eclipse view.

Comment: Thank you very much sunadorer, you've got me on the right path.

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Have fun exploring the Android world. Guess you can accept the answer then and get your first badge here at stackoverflow.