# Actionbar menu button clicked caused app to stop

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, menubar

i'm completely brand new to android developement. I'm currentlt trying to make a note taking app. The action bar will have 2 button, create and settings which lead users to create and settings page. The create button works perfectly fine but i dont know why whenever i run the app and click the settings button it doesnt lead me to the settings page, the app suddenly stop.

Here are my code

MainActivity.java

package com.example.sunny.mynote;

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.sunny.mynote.com.example.sunny.mynote.data.NoteDataSource;
import com.example.sunny.mynote.com.example.sunny.mynote.data.NoteItem;

import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static final int EDITOR_ACRIVITY_REQUEST = 1001;
    public static final int SETTINGS_REQUEST = 1003;
    private static final int MENU_DELETE_ID = 1002;
    private int currentNoteId;
    private NoteDataSource datasource;
    List<NoteItem> notesList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        datasource = new NoteDataSource(this);

        refreshDisplay();
    }

    private void refreshDisplay() {
        notesList = datasource.findAll();
        ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<NoteItem>(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, notesList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_create)
        {
            createNote();
        }
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_create) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createNote()
    {
        NoteItem note = NoteItem.getNew();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
        intent.putExtra("text", note.getText());
        startActivityForResult(intent, EDITOR_ACRIVITY_REQUEST);
    }

    private void Settings()
    {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        NoteItem note = notesList.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
        intent.putExtra("text", note.getText());
        startActivityForResult(intent, EDITOR_ACRIVITY_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == EDITOR_ACRIVITY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
            NoteItem note = new NoteItem();
            note.setKey(data.getStringExtra("key"));
            note.setText(data.getStringExtra("text"));
            datasource.update(note);
            refreshDisplay();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        currentNoteId = (int)info.id;
        menu.add(0, MENU_DELETE_ID, 0, "Delete");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == MENU_DELETE_ID)
        {
            NoteItem note = notesList.get(currentNoteId);
            datasource.remove(note);
            refreshDisplay();
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Settings.java

```
    package com.example.sunny.mynote;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by Sunny on 19/04/2015.
 */
public class Settings extends Activity {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.activity_note_editor, null);

    private RadioGroup RadioGroup1;
    private RadioButton rdbRed, rdbBlue, rdbOrange;
    private Button btnSave;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.settings, null);

        RadioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);

        RadioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId == R.id.rdbRed)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Red",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(checkedId == R.id.rdbBlue)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Blue",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Orange",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);

        rdbRed = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbRed);
        rdbBlue = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbBlue);
        rdbOrange = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbOrange);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteText);

        btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Save);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int selectedId = RadioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                if(selectedId == rdbRed.getId()) {
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                } else if(selectedId == rdbBlue.getId()) {
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0066FF"));
                } else {
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6600"));
                }
                finish();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

logs

```
04-21 22:02:11.583  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
04-21 22:02:11.603  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N9005_4.4.2_0040
04-21 22:02:11.603  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
04-21 22:02:11.603  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
04-21 22:02:11.603  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.example.sunny.mynote [ userId:0 | appId:10383 ]
04-21 22:02:11.603  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-21 22:02:11.613  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote I/dalvikvm﹕ Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 7...
04-21 22:02:11.693  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 22:02:11.693  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-21 22:02:11.723  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-21 22:02:11.743  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-21 22:02:11.763  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-21 22:02:11.763  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:11.763  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-21 22:02:11.763  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:11.773  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:11.793  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:11.793  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:11.823  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:12.868  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-21 22:02:12.898  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:12.948  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:12.948  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:12.998  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:12.998  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:13.758  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:13.758  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
04-21 22:02:13.758  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:02:13.758  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-21 22:02:13.758  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417e0da0)
04-21 22:02:13.768  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sunny.mynote, PID: 26636
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sunny.mynote/com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:212)
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:21)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 22:02:15.248  26636-26636/com.example.sunny.mynote I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 26636 S
```

IG: 9

Comment: please post the crash log

Comment: Does it show any error? logcat?

Comment: Need logcat trace to show your error. [See this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839539/android-effecient-way-to-read-logcat-output).

Comment: Updated.Please check

Comment: @LuluHarper it's not a logcat

Comment: post the *logcat* output not the console output

Comment: I dont understand, because the logcat output is completely blank

Comment: Did you add Settings activity to the manifest?

Comment: sorry my fault, updated the logcat

Comment: Yes, I did put <activity android:name=".Settings"/> in Manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inflate view inside or alter call of OnCreate() 
so move your line `View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.activity_note_editor, null);` inside oncreate() in Settings.java

Comment: I tried this but the app still crash when I hit settings button

Comment: any change in logcat or still same? also update code and logcat in your question

Comment: you have not removed View view =.. line that is out side of oncreate().. remove it...if you call getApplication() before call of onCreate() it will retrun null.. that's why you are getting null pointer

Comment: It works now I can go to the settings page. But another issue is when I click the save button in settings page the app will crash. This is the error in logcar 04-21 22:09:09.427  29767-29767/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this line in Settings:

```
private View view;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.activity_note_editor, null);
}
```

Comment: See your logcat again.

Comment: Little explanation. Member variables are initialized before constructor call. `LayoutInflater.from(getApplication())` called before constructor, and `getApplication()` returns null. `getApplication()` method returns application object only after activity was "attached". So you should do it in `onCreate()`.

Comment: You have to go through your logcat carefully. From your posted logcat this is the problem. Now maybe any other problem will happen. So go through your logcat..

Comment: This is my first day ever using android studio and to be honest, when i read the logcat I cant understand anything

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:212)
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:21)` This is taken from your logcat. This is your first problem. Like this you just search the error. See `(Settings.java:21)` This is the line which is error happen.

Comment: now I can go to settings page but when I click the save button in the settings page the app crashed. Please Help!!

Comment: This is the error in logcar 04-21 22:09:09.427 29767-29767/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called

Comment: If you still facing another error post as separate question. So that some other experts can view your problem and can help you..